# Git rebase vs merge with protected branches

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

Me and my team are using the Git Flow branch pattern with a master branch, a hotfix/release branch, a develop branch and feature branches.
We're hosting everything on GitLab.com and recently, we decided to protect the develop and master branches from pushing, so that it only accepts Merge requests.

Our usual feature workflow is the following :

1. (On develop) *git pull* to make sure that we've got the latest changes from the remote
2. *git checkout -b feature/wonderfulFeature* to create a new feature branch and automatically move to it
3. Code what needs to be done on the branch
4. *git add/commit* changes
5. *git checkout develop* and *git pull* again to make sure we have the latest changes
6. *git checkout feature/wonderfulFeature*
7. *git rebase develop* or *git rebase -i develop*
8. *git push -f origin feature/wonderfulFeature*
9. Open a MR on GitLab

But I've came across a problem : I've been brought up to share a feature branch with a colleague and rebased it onto develop, which you shouldn't ever do according to [the Golden Rule of rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing).

If it's not advised to rebase on shared branches, should I just replace `git rebase develop` by a `git merge develop` on my feature branch to make sure it is up to date?

Also, I'm pretty sure that we could improve this workflow so we don't have to `git push -f` on `origin feature/wonderfulFeature` everytime that we want to get the latest version of `develop`.